# Search results come from google.co.in instead of google.com

Tags: google-chrome

I am asking this question from India. I set my homepage to google.com instead of google.co.in AND I am a Chrome user. When I search from the homepage, results come from google.com...so far so good.
BUT when I search from the address bar (omnibar) I get results from google.co.in This is really irritating. Can someone please help?

If it helps to know, I set the google.com as the default search engine under the "Manage search engines" preference (NOT google.co.in).

Answer (score 1):

use the address www.google.com/ncr to visit the google.com site. 'ncr' supposedly stands for "no country redirect" implying you would not get redirected to your home-country specific google site.

jic it does not work, check if cookies are enabled in your browser settings. If not, enable them and restart your browser before trying out the 'google.com/ncr' site.

hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your PC in Germany, it would default to www.google.de.

Like it or not, it's dependent on your geographical location, not your browser settings :(

Comment: Strangest thing is I have three laptops only one laptop is doing this. Other laptops show results from google.com when I search from the address bar.
This laptop is also the latest one. I guess something changed in the most recent Chrome versions.
On other laptops started with old versions (whichever was the current Chrome version) and even after upgrades they kept behaving nice.

Any ways, above was an assumption. It would be nice to know how to make this new laptop also behave like other two old ones.

Comment: Hi - I don't believe it has anything to do with Chrome per se.  My experience was with Windows Vista and both Internet Explorer and Firefox, several years ago.  HOWEVER....  You might find these links helpful:  http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1224171&answer=179386&rd=1   http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-14111-how-to-change-from-google-xx-to-google-com